# Hibernate Criteria API - adding a criterion: string should be in collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have to following entity object

```
@Entity
public class Foobar {
    ...
    private List<String> uuids;
    ...
}
```

Now I'd like to make a criteria query which would fetch all Foobar pojos whose uuids list contains the string "abc123", I'm just not sure how to make the appropriate criterion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using a version of Hibernate that implements JPA 2.0.  Here's a JPA 2.0 solution that should work with any compliant implementation.

Please annotate `uuids` with JPA's `@ElementCollection` annotation.  Don't use Hibernate's `@CollectionOfElements` as mentioned in some of the other answer comments.  The latter has equivalent functionality but is [being deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1821).

`Foobar.java` will look approximately like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foobar implements Serializable {

    // You might have some other id
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> uuids;

    // Getters/Setters, serialVersionUID, ...

}
```

Here's how you can build a `CriteriaQuery` to select all `Foobar`s whose `uuids` contain "abc123".

```
public void getFoobars() {
{
    EntityManager em = ... // EM by injection, EntityManagerFactory, whatever

    CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Foobar> cq = b.createQuery(Foobar.class);
    Root<Foobar> foobar = cq.from(Foobar.class);

    TypedQuery<Foobar> q = em.createQuery(
            cq.select(foobar)
              .where(b.isMember("abc123", foobar.<List<String>>get("uuids"))));

    for (Foobar f : q.getResultList()) {
        // Do stuff with f, which will have "abc123" in uuids
    }
}
```

I made a self-contained proof-of-concept program while playing with this.  I can't push it out right now.  Please comment if you want the POC pushed to github.

Comment: Tryed with hibernate 3.6.7-Final and does not work (it seems to be a bug in hibernate).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old question, but I have just encountered this issue and found solution.

If you want to use Hibernate Criteria you can join your `uuids` collection and use its property `elements` to match elements. Just like that:

```
session.createCriteria(Foobar.class)
    .createAlias("uuids", "uuids")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("uuids.elements", "MyUUID"))
    .list()
```

Comment: You can also use instead of "elements" the constant `CollectionPropertyNames.COLLECTION_ELEMENTS`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Query as in the example below or you could convert this to a NamedQuery. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with Criteria.

```
List<Foobar> result = session
     .createQuery("from Foobar f join f.uuids u where u =: mytest")
     .setString("mytest", "acb123")
     .list();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found this post from one year ago, and I've made this method, if it can help anybody with the same problem I had a few hours ago.

```
    Public List<EntityObject> getHasString(String string) {
        return getSession().createCriteria(EntityObject.class)
                               .add(Restriction.like("property-name", string, MatchMode.ANYWHERE).ignoreCase();
                           .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                           .list();
```

Made the same with a group of strings too.

```
    public List<EntityObject> getByStringList(String[] tab) {
        Criterion c = Restrictions.like("property-name", tab[tab.length-1], MatchMode.ANYWHERE).ignoreCase();
        if(tab.length > 1) {
            for(int i=tab.length-2; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                c = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("property-name",tab[i], MatchMode.ANYWHERE).ignoreCase(), c);
            }
        }
        return getSession().createCriteria(EntityObject.class)
                               .add(c)
                           .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                           .list();
    }
```

It works with "or" statements, but can easily be replaced by "and" statements.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not supported out of the box by hibernate. See http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-869

Here is a workaround available in the jira ticket :

```
entityCriteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
  "fooAlias.id in (select e.id from foobar_table e, values_table v" + 
  " where e.id = v.entity_id and v.field = ?)", "abc123"), Hibernate.String)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the sqlRestriction from jira
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-869
seemed the best way to go for me since i heavily use criteria api. I had to edit Thierry's code so it worked in my case

Model:

```
@Entity
public class PlatformData
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long iID;

  private List<String> iPlatformAbilities = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Criteria call:

```
tCriteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
        "{alias}.id in (select e.id from platformData e, platformdata_platformabilities v"
          + " where e.id = v.platformdata_id and v.element = ? )", aPlatformAbility.toString(),
        Hibernate.STRING));
```

Answer (score -2):

For starters, I don't think Hibernate can map a `List<String>`. However, it can map a list of other entities.

So if your code was something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foobar {

    private List<EntityObject> uuids;
    ...
}
```

And the `EntityObject` has a `String`-property called `str`, the criteria could look like this:

```
List<Foobar> returns = (List<Foobar>) session
                .createCriteria.(Foobar.class, "foobars")
                .createAlias("foobars.uuids", "uuids")
                  .add(Restrictions.like("uuids.str", "%abc123%"))
                .list();
```

Comment: There's no problem in using a list of strings, just annotate it with @CollectionOfElements. Your solution requires me to make an extra entity class, something that I was hoping to avoid with this very specific question.