# ElementCollection createAlias in hibernate API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, jpa-2.0

does anyone know if and how the solution for [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735071/hibernate-criteria-api-adding-a-criterion-string-should-be-in-collection) (which is written in the JPA API) can be written using the hibernate criteria API?

To be more specific I have a Discussion entity that contains a list of participants (which is a list of usernames):

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "user_name")
@CollectionTable(name = "DISCUSSION_USER", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DISCUSSION_ID"))
@OrderColumn(name = "ORDER_INDEX")
private List<String> participants = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now I need to retrieve all Discussions where a given username is a participant.

If I would have created an entity for Participant this would be straightforward:

```
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Discussion.class);
    crit.createAlias("participants", "p");
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("p.userName", portalUsername));
```

But I can't create an alias with a non entity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Primary_keys_in_CollectionTable) what I wanted is not possible:

> The limitations of using an ElementCollection instead of a OneToMany is that the target objects cannot be queried, persisted, merged independently of their parent object. They are strictly privately-owned (dependent) objects, the same as an Embedded mapping. There is no cascade option on an ElementCollection, the target objects are always persisted, merged, removed with their parent.

So, I used a OneToMany instead.

Answer (score 34):

Late answer.

The correct propertyName for collection (annotated by **@ElementCollection**) is **`"elements"`** or constant [**CollectionPropertyNames#COLLECTION_ELEMENTS**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/persister/collection/CollectionPropertyNames.html#COLLECTION_ELEMENTS).

Try with the following answers

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Discussion.class);
crit.createAlias("participants", "p");

crit.add(Restrictions.eq("p.elements", portalUsername));
```

or use the constant **COLLECTION_ELEMENTS** instead

```
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("p." + CollectionPropertyNames.COLLECTION_ELEMENTS, portalUsername));
```

Comment: never too late for a good answer, I'll be sure to try this out once

Comment: Sorry didn't work... dammit.... But I'm using a very old release, may be this is fixed in the newer versions..

Comment: It seems from the usage of these constants in Hibernate source code, these are for HQL queries only.

Comment: You can do this in Hibernate 4, not Hibernate 3, I guess

Comment: Even a late answer is useful to others nearly 10 years after it was given. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us a more complete schema and query?

Also, Criteria API sucks. Try using QueryDSL, your query might look like:

```
HibernateQuery q=new HibernateQuery(getSession())
.from(QDiscussion.discussion).from(QDocument.document)
.where(QDocument.document.userName.in(QDiscussion.discussion.userNames))
.list(QDocument.document);
```