# Hibernate criteria query for Collection Table?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have following Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rule")
public class Rule implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "rule_id")
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Action.class)


     @CollectionTable(name = "rule_action", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id"))
        @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name = "action")
        private Set<Action> actions;

//After editing as per jbrookover's suggestion adding a new mapping
       @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id")
       private Set<RuleAction> ruleActions;


    }
```

Following is my Action

```
public enum Action {
    PHONE, EMAIL, POSTAL,PHONE_OR_EMAIL, SMS;
}
```

I want to fetch a List of rule having particular set of actions
I am trying this

```
 DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Rule.class,"rule");
 criteria = criteria.createAlias("rule.actions", "action");
 criteria.add(Restrictions.in("action.name",actionSet));
 return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

But getting 
org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association: exception..

***EDIT***
So after guidance from jbrookover I tried going for a wrapper class for Action named as RuleAction and was able to eshtablish the oneToMany relationship, Also I modified the query as follows

```
    Set<Action> act = new HashSet<Action>();
    act.add(Action.EMAIL);
    act.add(Action.POSTAL);

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Rule.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(SUPPORT_LANG, Language.valueOf("EN")))
            .createCriteria("ruleActions").add(Restrictions.in("action",act));
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

But this is returning me all the rule which are having either EMAIL or POSTAL but what I want is **all the rule having EMAIL and POSTAL both** Please help me in modifying the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, what you are trying to do, specifically, is not supported in Hibernate.  See this FAQ:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#Im_getting_orghibernateMappingException_collection_was_not_an_association_when_I_try_to_join_a_collection_of_components_with_Criteria_queries

I, too, was quite displeased with this.  As you can see, though, they've tried to fix it an have been unable to do so and have put it on the community to deal with it.  You have a few options:

1. Use HQL to run the query.
2. Re-write your collection association as an actual entity class with a single Enum field.

You can do something like this:

```
 @Entity
 public class ActionWrapper {

      public Action action;
 }
```

Then, update your associations and query accordingly so that `Rule` has a `Set<ActionWrapper>`.  There are other workarounds, but you essentially cannot use `Criteria` and `@ElementCollection` together.

**Update**

In order to restrict the query further, to ensure that you get Rules that meet BOTH actions, you need to run the subquery and do a conjunction - 'and' - of the matched values.  Something like this should work:

```
 Criteria subCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("ruleActions");
 Disjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
 for (Action a : act)
    and.add(Restrictions.eq("action", a)
 subCriteria.add(and);
```

At the end, you may find duplicate results.  This is common and can be eliminated by adding this:

```
 criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

I can't speak for the efficiency of this code - HQL may be better in the long run.  However, I've done something similar in other projects and haven't encountered any issues.

Comment: hi jbrookover ..thanks!! As per ur suggestion I am trying to proceed through Wrapper Class. and have modified your answer as per what I am doing ..so that it may help other who may face same problem

Comment: @AnupamGupta Updated to include the restricted query.

Comment: thanks @jbrookover as of now I used Hql..and quite occupied to use your solution will soon change it as per your suggestion and will also update here in SO, so that it may be helpful for others

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without wrapping your enums and using ResultTransformers is this:

```
        @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name = " action")
        @JoinTable(name = "rule_action", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id") })
        private Set<Action> actions;
```

Query:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Rule.class,"rule");
criteria = criteria.createAlias("rule.actions", "action");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("action." + CollectionPropertyNames.COLLECTION_ELEMENTS, actionSet));
return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

That's what worked for me with Hibernate 4.1.6.Final. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873021/elementcollection-createalias-in-hibernate-api/10638064#10638064).

Answer (score 1):

The criteria query looks fine. Suppose we have tables:

```
rule(id, name,...)
action(id, name,..)
rule_action(id, rule_id, action_id,...) -- (or rule_id+action_id as  a composite pkey)
```

The mapping should be as follows:

```
public class Rule {
   ...
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rule")
   private Set<Action> actions;
   ...
}

public class Action {
   ...
   @JoinTable(
      name="rule_action",
      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="action_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="rule_id")}
   )
   private Set<Rule> rules;
   ...
}
```

This way your criteria query should work.

Comment: HI can you please let me know how to write a hibernate criteria query for above case I want to add criteria in such a way that my query should return all rules having action A & D (out of set of actions {A,B,C,D,E})

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, apparently I'm bad at carefully reading the questions. The initial answer was totally misleading, so I completely rewrote it. Take a look.

Comment: actually I am bit concerned about changing the mapping since the current code is using CollectionTable. And the current mapping is extensively used, so I just want to be sure that I am not breaking the existing code.. Does changing the mapping like the one you told will effect the existing system?

Comment: moreover I am sorry that I didn't mention that my Action is of type Enum .. I have updated the question with Action entity. And have started Bounty of 50 points.