# Hibernate criteria one-to-many with embedded table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I've got tables A, B, C where B is association table with adding columns

| A |  1 .. *  | B |  * .. 1  | C |

Entity A with list of B entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {
    //id

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bPK.a", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<B> listB; 

    // getters, setters
}
```

Entity B has embedded PK

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BPK bPK; 

    // added columns
    // getters, setters
}
```

Embedded primary key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class BPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="i_a", nullable=false)
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="i_c", nullable=false)
    private C c;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Entity C

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
public class C {
    @Column(name = "i_c")
    private Long iC;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name; 

    // getters, setters
}
```

...and I would like to get such objects A which has associated object C with concrete name

I tried to do it this way but it doesnt work

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);  
criteria.createAlias("listB", "bList")
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("bList.bPK.c.name", "name", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

I have got following exception:

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: bPK.c.name

thank you for help

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? Did you just use HQL ?

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this problem was reported as a bug.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6963

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that is that Hibernate is looking for column `bPk.c.name` in your `bList (A class)`, and there is obviously no such column. What you are trying to achieve can be done my multiple aliases (when creating an alias, Criteria is also doing a join on your current table with that one).

Thus:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);  
criteria.createAlias("listB", "bList")
    .createAlias("bList.bPk", "bPk")
    .createAlias("bPk.c", "c")
    .add(Restrictions.like("c.name", "name", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

I think the MatchMode.ANYWHERE is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it still doesnt work. But now I get another exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'c3_.name' in 'where clause'

Comment: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'c3_.name' in 'where clause'

Comment: Where is the `3` in `c3_.name` coming from?

Comment: I think that hibernate index that aliases somehow. I had tried this way with aliases before I sent this post and it didnt work. When I throw away the embedded primary key from B entity and left the index property like a non-id column then it works fine. So I guess problem is somewhere in the embedded table.

Comment: You are probably right. I am also curious to see a solution for this. I cannot help any further though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a way to reference a collection element in a `@CollectionTable` with hibernate criteria for a whole day ! finally I found this :

[ElementCollection createAlias in hibernate API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873021/elementcollection-createalias-in-hibernate-api)

I needed to reference a basic element (Integer) in a collection, hope it works for non-basic elements as well. In case someone is lost like me , don't give up and turn to HQL, cause there is a solution!!! :)