# How to perform subquery on an @ElementCollection within the same entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria, eclipselink, criteria-api

Consider the following entity.

```
@Entity
public class Member {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String memberName;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="memberId"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name="prop")
    @Column(name="val")
    private Map<String, Boolean> checklist;

    /** usual getters and setters **/
}
```

Assuming the above entity creates two table; member and member_checklist; is it possible for me to achieve the following sql statement with jpa 2 criteria api?

```
select * from member where id not in (
    select memberid from member_checklist where prop in (2));
```

I've read [Hibernate Criteria API - adding a criterion: string should be in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735071/hibernate-criteria-api-adding-a-criterion-string-should-be-in-collection) but I still can't figure out how I can achieve my goal.

Looking forward to some expert opinions.

Comment: It is possible with JPA 2 Criteria-api, but because of Hibernate bug explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580614/jpa-criteriabuilder-join-maps it does not work as long as you use Hibernate

Comment: @MikkoMaunu If I don't use hibernate, can you tell me how I can achieve the above with criteria-api?